# what is make file?

Tags: brew-framework, brewmp

What is the need of Make File? IN which situation we have to alter that file for Brew Application?

Answer (score 0):

The makefile is usually used to build for the device (ARM) build of the project (with visual studio being used to build for the emulator). Visual Studio will run the makefile when you do the device build.

Answer (score 0):

Small addition - makefiles used in Visual Studio only for MOD1 application, whereas they aren't used for compiling MOD apps.

Comment: what is he difference between MOD and MOD1? May I Know?

Comment: Please see https://brewmobileplatform.qualcomm.com/devnet/prod/resources/devEx/library/techguides/c/General/MOD_MOD1/html_out/frameset.html

Answer (score 0):

As joseph said makefiles are used to build the source files in linux projects, advantage of makefile is you can write a general script irrespective of dependency files. and even if you change a single file in your file then you dont have to compile the whole source code again. only the file which is changed is compiled again and the files which are dependent on them are   compiled. you can check out tutorial on the makefile at http://sagarsakre.blogspot.in/2012/09/understanding-makefile-for-beginners.html .....